# Modify an existing UIView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've tried to modify a few traits of an existing `UIView` such as its `frame` and its `backgroundColor`, and nothing happens any time I do it. I've looked at some of the answers on here, but none of them have worked for me. I've been able to modify a UIView and then place it as a subview before, but never one that was in the xib or storyboard from the start (xib because I've been working an old project at my work). To be clear the views I've been trying to modify are not self.view, always subviews that were created before hand.

example code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *toEdit;

[_toEdit setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, 200, 200)];
```

Comment: Did you attach your IBOutlet in your xib?

Comment: Do you use autolayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW6), have you tried connecting the elements in the xib to the code throughout `Outlets`? Ctrl+click on the ui element in the Interface Builder element and release on the relative property of the relative header.

In case you use an [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html), the `Frame` system changes totally and you will not be able anymore (lets say) to edit position directly if not using `Constraints`.

Comment: I found that there was a piece of code updating the frame past my changes to it in the code, but in my test project it was autolayout.